# Which method is more efficient?

Tags: c++

I am playing around with C++ for the purpose of learning to better write efficient code and algorithm. I am trying to solve a question very trivial on how many times an integer is divisible by 2 I came up with below methods :

```
int timesTwo1 ( int x ) {

    long s = clock();
    int count = 0;
    while( x%2 == 0 && (x>>=1) && (++count) && ( (x ^ INT_MAX) & 1 != 0  ) ); 
    long e = clock();

    std::cout << "timesTwo1 : " << (e - s) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) * 10e6 << "us\n";
return count;
}


int timesTwo2 ( int  x ) {
    long s = clock();
    int count = 0;
    while ( x%2 == 0 && (x/=2) && (++count) );
    long e = clock();

    std::cout << "timesTwo2 : " << (e - s) / double (CLOCKS_PER_SEC) * 10e6 << "us\n"; 

    return count;
}
```

on my machine ubuntu 14.04LTS 64 bit intel processor 5i series the execution time takes 10us (micro seconds) I see timesTwo2 is more readable but which one is more efficient? thanks

Comment: Do not get into the trap of micro optimization, It is inherently dangerous as 1) You lose the bigger picture of where the performance problems are. 2) You start writing code that is difficult to read and hence difficult to maintain. Besides the compiler is better to optimize at this level most of the time. Instead use profiling to identify where problems occur. Please do not forget the 80/20 rule

Comment: How did you actually measure? Calling once won't give much reliable benchmark results.

Comment: If you want to sacrifice readability even more, you can change `x % 2` into `x & 1`

Comment: EdHeal I agree with you, however I am playing around. Yes, I am calling this only once and I receive the same numbers. zereges thank you for the suggestion :) I think method 1 has more instructions than method two apparently however method two has some background operations as well. At the end of the day I am just playing around... thanks

Comment: @xiarnousx why not use log2?

Comment: If you really want to make it faster, find a better algorithm. See http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/10/implementing-gccs-builtin-functions.html, or look up `__builtin_ffs`.

Comment: I think `x>>=1` can lead to undefined behavior because `x` is a signed int. Unless I'm remembering wrong...

Comment: If you look at the generated assembly for these (with full optimisation) I would expect them to be nearly identical. The compiler is generally better at this sort of  "peephole optimisation" than you are.

Comment: @AlanStokes thanks for the reference

Comment: @JamesRoot you are right should be unsigned thanks

Comment: I think you're on the right track. People are generally not very good at guessing which method of doing something is faster. If you want to know - time it. :-)

Comment: @xiarnousx - I think 10 microseconds is *good enough*. You don't have to make code "more efficient" until you have hit a bottleneck somewhere. If you get the time down to 8 us, nobody will notice the difference.